# Bootstrap uncollapse div button not working with Rails 5

Tags: jquery, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to make a grocery list sorted by categories. I want an arrow next to each category that will hide/unhide all the items that belong to that category. I believe I have the link pointed at the div I want to hide, but clicking the link doesn't effect the collapsed div.

https://pastebin.com/JmjkpzE0

```
    <div class="categories">
        <% current_user.categories.each do |category| %>
            <h3>
                <%= category.name %>
                <a href="#<%= category.name %>" data-toggle="collapse">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span>
                </a>
</h3>
            <br>
            <div id="<%= category.name %>" class="collapse">
                <% category.user_items.each do |item| %>
                    <%= item.name %>
                <% end %>
            </div>
        <% end %>
    </div>
```

Here is what my terminal says when I click the link that's supposed to toggle my divs

```
  Rendered lists/new.html.erb within layouts/application (22.3ms)
  Rendered layouts/_rails_default.html.erb (42.0ms)
  Rendered layouts/_shim.html.erb (0.4ms)
  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (0.6ms)
  Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.3ms)
Completed 200 OK in 78ms (Views: 68.9ms | ActiveRecord: 8.7ms)
```

Not sure if it's supposed to be rendering all that. I should also mention that this is all in a form, which may be an issue. I was originally going to use a button, but the button would POST to my lists#create when pressed...

Comment: Where you are closing `<h3>`?

Comment: You should use `data-target="#<%= category.name %>"` attribute in the `<a>` tag

Comment: fixed the h3 tag

Answer (score 1):

First, you're missing the closing `<h3>` tag. Then you need to tell bootstrap, which element should it collapse / uncollapse on click. I should look something like:

```
<h3>
   <%= category.name %>
   <a href="#<%= category.name %>" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#<%= category.name %>">
     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span>
   </a>
 </h3>   
 <div id="<%= category.name %>" class="collapse">
   <% category.user_items.each do |item| %>
     <%= item.name %>
   <% end %>
 </div>
```

EDIT: Also are you sure category name is the best option for id? What will happen if the name will not be unique? Try using `category.id` instead.

Comment: I tried your code, but it still will not toggle anything. Good thinking on the category.id though I hadn't thought of that.

PS: I installed Bootstrap via gem, not manually, so as far as I know all the necessary JS/JQuery files are present.

Comment: Have you included all necessary files? Just to install the gem is not enough. See instructions here and make sure you followed them: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass#a-ruby-on-rails. Double check that bootstrap js file is included (you can use your browser console, or inspect the source code of your rendered page). Also check if you don't have any JS errors in console.

Comment: Ow wait which version of bootstrap are you using? I believe collapse as you are trying to use it here is only in version 4.

Comment: Ok, it seems I was missing "//= require bootstrap-sprockets" from my application.js. Now the toggle will work for a split second; as in it will display the hidden div for a brief moment and then hide it again. I can't help but feel it's got something to do with the page getting completely re-rendered each press, or is that supposed to happen?

using 'bootstrap-sass', '3.3.7'

Answer (score 1):

Alright, I think the issue was actually my  tags re-rendering the page each time I clicked the dropdown icon. The same thing happens when I used  tags because I was inside a form it would actually post.

I decided to just use a div with this script

```
              <script>
                $(document).ready(function () {
                    $('.data-toggle').collapse();
                });
              </script>
```

And it works perfectly.

```
<% provide(:title, "New List") %>
<div class="jumbotron">
    <div class="new-list">
        <h2>New List</h2>
        <%= form_for @list, url: list_path, html: {class: "form-signin"} do |f| %>
            <%= f.text_field :name, placeholder: "Name your list (optional)" %>
            <div class="categories">
                <% current_user.categories.each do |category| %>
                    <h3>
                       <%= category.name %>
                       <div class="dropdown-button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#<%= category.name %>">
                         <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span>
                       </div>
                     </h3>   
                     <div id="<%= category.name %>" class="collapse">
                       <% category.user_items.each do |item| %>
                         <%= item.name %>
                       <% end %>
                     </div>
                <% end %>
            </div>
        <% end %>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- dropdown button script -->
<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
      $('.data-toggle').collapse();
  });
</script>
```

It's a little messy, but it does exactly what I need. Thanks folks.

Also if anyone else has this issue, make sure your application.js file is set up like this:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```